# redirecting outputs of multiple c file to a single file in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a c program. I compiled it using gcc. After running the executable file. I saved the output to a separate file.

```
$ ./a.out > outputs
```

Then I compiled another program and ran it. I directed to output to the same output file where it erased the old content and wrote the new content. How do i direct all the outputs to the same file with out erasing the previous content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output redirection `>` in the `./a.out > outputs` will create a new file(outputs) every time. Instead of that use

```
./a.out >> outputs
```

`>>` will append new data to old one every time.